# Dividir cadena de string en un array

Tags: php, array, string

La verdad es que tengo un problema de dividir una cadena de string en un solo array. Tengo en ejemplo, la siguiente cadena:

```
etiqueta1_bg-warning, etiqueta2_bg-primary, etiqueta3_bg-success
```

Y necesito dividirla de la siguiente manera en un array:

```
0: "nombre_etiqueta" => etiqueta1,
    "color" => "bg-warning"

1: "nombre_etiqueta" => etiqueta2,
    "color" => "bg-primary"

2: "nombre_etiqueta" => etiqueta3,
    "color" => "bg-success"
```

Y así sucesivamente con el resto de los valores, para posteriormente guardar ese array en la base datos que también me gustaría saber cómo hacerlo. Sé que en el primer paso, el explode juega una parte fundamental, pero solo necesito un array. No varios en uno solo. Si alguien puede ayudarme, sería de mucha ayuda.

Comment: Considera leer [ask], editar y mostrarnos lo que llevas al momento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes partir el string y con foreach seccionas cada elemento integrandolo a un array vacío.

```
<?php
    $array = [];
    $items = explode(', ', $string);
    foreach ($items as $item) {
         $elements = explode('_', $item);
         array_push($array, [
              'nombre_etiqueta' => $elements[0],
              'color' => $elements[1]
         ]);
    }
    var_dump($array)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha funcionado!